# Cannot select iOS Phone Simulator in Android Studio for Flutter

Tags: ios, android-studio, flutter, simulator, watch

I have an issue. I started to code in Android Studio and I want to select iOS Simulator. However, I can select only option `Open iOS Simulator` which opens.. a watch!

How could I launch a phone as a simulator?

I tried going into Simulator itself, but couldn't find any ways how to do it.

Answer (score 6):

Open iOS Simulator externally first. Now, open Xcode, Select your latest Xcode version in `Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations -> Command Line Tools` 
Now, go to Terminal and run `flutter doctor` See if it shows any iOS device connected.

If yes, then you're done. Now you can see opened simulator can be seen in `Flutter Device Selection` and used to run your flutter application in iOS Simulator.

If No, then open terminal of project and run `xcrun simctl list`, from list of devices copy UID of wanted device and run `xcrun simctl boot *SELECTED_UID*`

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, @Sachin. I have solved issue by mentioning my solution in the answers (which is exactly same as yours). Cheers

Answer (score 1):

After extensive research, I found a solution.
First, go to your xcode.
`xcode -> Preferences -> Components` and install selected iOS version.

After installation is finished, head to `Android Studio` go to `Terminal` tab and write `xcrun simctl list` - you will get list of devices. Select which one you want to use, copy UID (bunch of numbers) and use it with this command `xcrun simctl boot *YOUR_DEVICE_ID*`

Hope it helps for someone with same issue!